# How many trees should be generated in a random forest?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, hyper-parameters, random-forests

What are ways of determining the number of trees to be generated in a random forest algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of estimators in Random Forest is a hyper-parameter. If you are using SKLearn's Random Classifier you can use one of the following techniques to find a (near) optimal hyperparameter settings (Note:You can tweak other hyperparameters like `min_leaf_size` etc as well with this approach);

**GridSearchCV** You can specify a grid of all the hyperparameters and a scoring criteria. This function will then evaluate **all** combinations of these parameters for you and return the setting which performed best on the validation set.

**RandomSearchCV** You can specify a grid of all the hyperparameters and a scoring criteria. This function will then evaluate **n randomly choosen** combinations of these parameters for you and return the setting which performed best on the validation set.

**Bayesian Optimization** You can treat the hyperparameter settings and corresponding score as a black box function and use exploitation-exploration paradigm using bayesian optimization.